# how to use gitignore in flutter to make sure ios and android versions don't override settings of each other?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, git, github

I have an app that consists of many small games inside it, and i use windows os for android and macOS for iOS publishing. While i know the main changes are done in the "lib" directory of the flutter, while i code... some of the settings which are platform specific remain on each side. I have some idea of using gitignore for both directories "android" and "ios", but i'm not so clear on how to do it, so that only the changes in the "lib" directory should be syncronyzed. Please advice a way to do it, so that i would have less headache changing things manually each time. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following lines to your .gitignore.

```
 #Ignore the 'android and ios' folder
 android/
 ios/
```

Then clear git cache `git rm -r --cached .`